# Creating OSGi for utility jar and using it with Websphere EAR

Tags: jar, osgi, bundle, utility

I have unsuccessfully tried to find any kind of documentation about using OSGi bundles as a Utility jars in a Websphere application.

I am writing some common classes to be used across the organisation which depend on some third party libraries like log4j, commons-lang etc.  I would like to create an OSGi bundle for the utility which can be used by different websphere applications as utility jars like other dependent jars, but for this one I wouldn't need to add its dependent jars to every application that uses the utility I am creating.

I have found OSGi tutorials, but nothing about using them in simple websphere app.

How can I achieve this?  Are there any tutorials or documentation that will guide me in how to do this?

Comment: What build system do you use? Is your websphere app an OSGi bundle?

Comment: What version of WebSphere are you using? Is it the Liberty profile or traditional WebSphere?

Comment: @Christian S - No, my websphere app is not an OSGi bundle, it is a simple EAR.  I would like to use an OSGi bundle with a non-OSGi EAR. Is this possible?

Comment: @Holly C - It is Websphere 8.5 full version ( not liberty )

Answer (score 0):

Likely you need `maven` and build jars with dependencies: [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

Comment: I cannot use Maven. But the link you provided also doesn't seem to be creating an OSGi bundle. I am specifically looking to create OSGi bundle and using it for the purposes mentioned above, if that is possible.

Comment: Well, maven [can build OSGi bundles](http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/develop-osgi-bundles-using-maven-bundle-plugin/), there's [a plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) for it. But if you can't go with maven, then, probably I don't have an instant answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know OSGi bundle contents can never be seen outside the OSGi framework. So unless websphere does something special here this can not work.